# In Vuetify, why each breakpoint is 16px less than other framework standards. e.g 1904 instead of 1920?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, breakpoints

I have a screen with 1920px wide. When my browser is in fullscreen (1920px), my vuetify app gets very wide because it exceeds 1904px breakpoint. But I think the xl breakpoint must begin from 1921 (not 1905) and in 1920px wide screens.

In the vuetify doc, it is mentioned that the xl breakpoint is 16px less because of scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the following:

```
* -16px on desktop for browser scrollbar
```

You can read this [website](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/).

Comment: tnx for your answer, I know it is for browser scrollbar, but in 1920px width desktop screen, the screen width is 1920 even the browser has the scrollbar, making vuetify exceed 1904 breakpoint and go to 4k screen scope.

I want my app to obey lg screen rules up to 1920.